# Find My Phone App shows my IPOD Touch is in California, but I have it with me in Missouri

Tags: find-my-iphone

I have all of mine and my kids Apple devices set up on Find My Phone.  We're always misplacing one of the ten!  Today when I went to find my daughters IPOD Touch it shows that the location of it is near Santa Rosa California.  We live in St. Louis MO.  We played the sound and found the touch in her bedroom, but it's still showing on the map that it is in California.  What can be making it show that it's in a different location than it is?

Answer (score 1):

Since iPods don't use cellular or GPS data it relies on wifi triangulation to get the closest GPS coordinates. I would simply reset your iPod touch so it can reboot based off the current network.

Answer (score 0):

Location Services could be off. It may be showing the last location it "saw" it (which obviously isn't correct)

Comment: Thanks.  It was a good thought!  I double checked and location services is turned on.  I tried turning it off and then back on hoping it might "reset", but to no good.  It still shows the Touch is in California!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a VPN on the iPod?  That could make it think it's somewhere it isn't.  Also, what is your ISP?  When I use a T-Mobile hotspot, I have noticed my location always defaults to Seattle, WA.

Comment: Just letting you know that the question being 6 years old and the OP hasn't been seen for the same amount of time, it's very, very unlikely that you'll see any movement on this.

Comment: Oh wow you're right!  This was somehow on my homepage.  Thanks for letting me know @Allan!

Comment: The system periodically cycles old posts to the top of the stack.  I just wanted to bring your attention to it so you don't spend time writing answers that don't have a chance to earn you any reputation.  That said..it doesn't hurt anything to "close the loop" especially if you can link to it for other questions and it earns some votes.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks again!